# FilteringTextInputFormatter clear all the value inside the textformfield if one character doesn't matches the regex

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the inputFormatters inside the textformfield I've noticed that if one character doesn't match the regex then the whole text inside the textformfield will be cleared.

Update: I've noticed that the problem is with the regex because when I try different regex that contains numbers only it works fine

```dart
inputFormatters:  <TextInputFormatter>[
  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r"^[\x00-\x7F’]+$"))
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the $ sign in the end of the regex solved the problem